how can i customize the laravel cashier's default user model/table
i want to use custom table for laravel cashier default is users, laravel cashier create custom columns in user table, i don't want that thing.
Am developing a site for tenants and want to use tenant table for cashier.
I'm using user table just for admin/domain only one user, for other users i am using tenants table and want to make it default for subscription 'laravel cashier'. if a new visitor/user subscribe a package, his data should store in tenants table with subscription plan details.
i looked over laravel cashier document but couldn't make sense,
everything i want to store in customize table 'tenant' not in default user table

You always can publish the config, extend the base classes and override methods.

May you explain little bit more

You can extend the base clases from laravel cashier, you can override the properties of the exended clases, if they are not private, of course. Knowing the laravel stucture, you can search which class from cashier response for your needs, then just extend it and override the class property responding for the table name. Also, don't forget to update the migrations as well.
